# SWRevealViewController from one controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm working with `SWRevealViewController` to have a side menu on an application. It works as expected from the side menu to a controller. What I'd like to do now is use `SWRevealViewController` again from one controller to another (both `UITableViewController`).

**From Side Menu to Controller 1 to Controller 2:**

[image]

This is what I've tried to do so far:

Set up the `Real View Controller Segue` from the Interface Builder to the second Controller with `identifier "articlesSegue"`.

And in the first Controller I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `prepareForSegue` to show the second Controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set selected issue to var
    _selectedIssue = _feedItems[indexPath.row];

    // Manually call segue to detail view controller
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"articlesSegue" sender:self];
}

#pragma mark Segue

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    TableViewController *tableVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    // data used in the second Controller
    tableVC.self.type = @"category";
    tableVC.self.data = [_selectedIssue.ID stringValue];
}
```

Selecting an item from the list is displayed as selected but nothing happens.

[image]

I've tested it out using a Push Segue and it worked, still I prefer it to working with `SWRevealViewController`.

I did find this question but I'm not too sure how it has to be implemented, [SWRevealViewController - manually switch to another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096326/swrevealviewcontroller-manually-switch-to-another-view).

Comment: what the result u need, u want to seque from side menu to main VC or Main VC to another VC, can u show ur screen shot

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik screenshot added to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Anbu.Kathik explained I could not use the `SWReveal` to move from `Controller` to another `Controller`. I've solved it by using the same `TableViewController`, I've added a property `type` to check which is the current 'tableview' and simply updating the table when an item is selected on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // check type of current tableview - if category display article
    if ([self.type isEqualToString:@"category"]) {
        // display single article
        _selectedArticle = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        // else if issue display list of articles on the same TableViewController
        _selectedIssue = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
        self.type = @"category";
        self.data = [_selectedIssue.ID stringValue];
        [_homeModel downloadItems:self.type :self.data];
    }
}
```

Using `[self.tableView reloadData]` reloads the table with new data.