# Navigate to a Specific view on click on a push notification with Reveal

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I want to navigate to a specific viewcontroller when the I click on a push notification.

I have written this code in my didReceiveRemoteNotification method.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deals") as! FYIDealsVC
        let naviVC:UINavigationController? = self.window?.rootViewController?.revealViewController().frontViewController as? UINavigationController
        naviVC?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

But it's giving me this error which crashes the app.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

There are many posts with navigation controller or just presenting the viewcontroller. But I want to navigate to the specific view with reveal.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that the storyboard ID of the given screen is "deals" and that it has the class `FYIDealsVC`?

Comment: Yes, in this line only it breaks down

let naviVC:UINavigationController? = self.window?.rootViewController?.revealViewController().frontViewController as? UINavigationController

Comment: are you sure you are getting object of navigation controller debug this line i think you are  getting nil in this line self.window?.rootViewController?.revealViewController().frontViewController as? UINavigationController

Comment: Hi, yes im getting nil in that line

Comment: i have another solution for this try with window.rootviewcontroller   or you can use notificationcenter to navigate

Comment: sharing my way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a another solution for this Try this:-

**First Option :-**

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
    "deals") as! FYIDealsVC

  // setup revelview controller and root with window 

    self.window?.rootViewController = //object of revelViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Second option :-**

```
 //  in Landing Screen from where you can easily navigate to the target 
  viewcontroller :-
```

in  Landing VC:-

```
   viewdidload:- 
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
    #selector(self.navigationForNotification(notification:)), name: 
   NSNotification.Name(rawValue:PushNavigationIdentifier), object: nil)


// Selector Method :-

 func navigationForNotification(notification:Notification) {
  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "deals") as! FYIDealsVC
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)  
}


 in appDelegate :- 
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
   didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
                  NotificationCenter.default.post(name: 
   NSNotification.Name(PushNavigationIdentifier), object: userInfo)

   }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answers. The first one doesn't seem to work

and regarding the second, it's working . But you can add observer to only one class. Otherwise it will be called multiple times. I need it be called in every class.

Comment: define only in landing screen and make sure observer should add only once  .set a bool with userdefault change the value when observer added.

Comment: yeah, but if the user is in another class , that class fails to catch that notification and do the function required. I want whatever the class catch the notification , but execute the required function just once.

Comment: are you using SWrevelvc ?

Comment: Actually the prob exists with me too. Even if I am adding NotificationCenter on the basecontroller then in that case it is calling but unable to navigate to the next screen when App in in active state, for this what I have done I have added the observer for every screen and removed the observer from ViewWillDisappear. But if it is background then it was working fine.

Comment: is target screen is added on side menu.you are accessing FYIDealsVC screen  from side menu.

Comment: if you are switching  view from side menu then follow this link to change programatically  viewcontroller https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096326/swrevealviewcontroller-manually-switch-to-another-view

Comment: Hi, the NotificationCenter approach worked for me along with @Prakash's answer. I have added a base view controller. With that I could add and remove notification observers in ViewDidApppear and ViewWillDisappear methods to all the classes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NavodaP we are here to help and guide each other. It's a part of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like error happens when you force unwrap FYIDealsVC. 
Can you use

```
let vc = FYIDealsVC()
```

instead of

`let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deals") as! FYIDealsVC`